# Sabre Web service air cancellation and refund flow

Tags: php, soap, sabre

I have done air ticket cancellation service. but I don't know how to refund the amount. If anyone know how to refund the balance amount. Please provide the  flow of refund web-service. we used here PHP, and soap API.

Answer (score 1):

Sabre has a webservice for an Automated Refunds ([TKT_RefundRQ](https://beta.developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/fulfill/auto_price_air_refunds)). However, the list of aircompanies supporting the Automated Refunds flow is very limited, you may find it [here](https://agencyeservices.sabre.com/~/media/eServices/Sharepoint%20Folders/AgencyeServices_Richmedia/Refunds/Documents/Automated%20Refunds%20Participating%20Carriers.pdf.ashx).

I guess in most cases you should read fare rules (cat. 16) to find out what penalties apply. You may use either **StructureFareRulesRQ** for structured or **OTA_AirRulesLLSRQ** for plain text fare rules.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Save your Ticket order into another table. You need to put the order value (Money) . into the table

**step 2:**
when somebody orders a ticket you have to Cut that ticket price and save a new price in your amount table

( Now for example You have a amount of 200$ in your amount table)
( You ordered a ticket , store that ticket ID )
(get ticket amount using Join query ) or ( You can store the amount in the order table )

**Step3:**

Get you amount from amount table and subtract with the order amount

Here you go... got whole idea?

Happy coding ...

Comment: Thanks for replay, we want know what is the exact  web-service for refund, after the ticket cancelled in sabre reservation system.

Comment: Actually I don't have any idea about sabre reservation system , didn't they provide any kind of API for this?

Comment: VoidTicketLLSRQ for voiding ticket and VoidTicketLLSRQ for cancelling PNR. i am not very sure about the refund amount, please let me know if you know the refund flow.